# Network protocol object serialization in C++

Tags: c++, networking, cross-platform, stream

I'm writing some C++ code that will have to send data over TCP/IP. I want this code to be portable on Linux/Windows/Osx. Now, as it is the first time I write portable network code, I basically need some simple functions to add to certain objects like:

```
class myclass{

...member...

public:

  string serialize(){
    std::ostringstream out();
    out << member1;
    out << member2;
    out << member3;
    return out.str();
  }

}
```

... which is all I need for now. Anyway I started reading ostringstream related docs and turns out the binary/text problem. In fact it will convert line breaks to the right sequence of everysystem. Suppose for example that a member is a pointer to const char* foo = "Hello\nMan\n", that will be translated in certain byte sequence on linux, another on windows... and so on. My bytes will go on a packet over the internet, a different OS machine will read them and I think trouble will occurr... Now I read that I might initialize `ostringstream` with `ostringstream(ios::bin)`... Will it solve the problem (provided that I will use a de-serialization function that will use a `istringstream(ios::bin)`??? I'm confused about the whole picture, if you may spend a few clarifying lines that'll be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do it all manually if there are great libraries like [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) that you can build on?

From their goals:

> Data Portability - Streams of bytes created on one platform should be readable on any other.

Also of interest for you might be points 4 and 5:

> - Deep pointer save and restore. That is, save and restore of pointers saves and restores the data pointed to.
> - Proper restoration of pointers to shared data.

Comment: yeah I think I'll go for boost serialization... I thought it to be diffucult but after a look at the tutorial I'm already using it. Seems a good choice. Thank you gf and Dirk.

Answer (score 8):

Seconded -- use a tested serialization library like the aforementioned [**Boost::Serialization**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) or [**Google Protocol Buffers**](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/).  These should not introduce further dependencies.

If you are open to a whole new framework, then Qt also has [**Qt Serialization**](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qdatastream.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) framework. It provides serialization/deserialization with CORBA marshalling (see classes [ACE_InputCDR](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/5.7.8/html/ace/a00296.html) and [ACE_OutputCDR](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/Doxygen/5.7.8/html/ace/a00461.html)). 
If you don't know ACE, this is a huge framework including a complete CORBA-Runtime. But you only need the core ACE libraries for serialization.