# C++ objects serialization for Linux

Tags: c++, linux, serialization

I'm doing a program that needs send and receive data over the network. I never dealt with object serialization. I readed about some recommendations about Boost and Google Protocol Buffers. For use in Linux which is the best?

If you know some other I will appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855628/network-protocol-object-serialization-in-c

Comment: How could the *best* be determined without knowing the specific requirements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) to serialize objects and transmit them over a socket. It's a very flexible library, objects can be serialized intrusively if you have access to them

```
class Foo
{
public:
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & _foo;
        ar & _bar;
    }

    int _foo;
    int _bar;
};
```

or non-intrusively if you don't have access to the object you need to serialize

```
namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, Foo& f, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & f._foo;
    ar & f._bar;
}

} // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost
```

There are tricks to serialize Foo if it does not expose its members (`_foo` and `_bar` here), the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#constructors) explains this quite well. To serialize `Foo`, you use an object in the `boost::archive` namespace: text, binary, or xml.

```
std::stringstream ss;
boost::archive::text_oarchive ar( ss );
Foo foo;
foo._foo = 1;
foo._bar = 2;
ar << foo;
```

reconstructing the archive into a Foo object is done like so

```
boost::archive::text_iarchive ar( ss );
Foo foo
ar >> foo;
```

Note this example is fairly trivial, and obviously when you introduce a network you'll be using sockets and buffers.

Comment: @Lucas, you should accept one of our answers when you are satisfied it has answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are transferring data over the network, I suggest using a binary form of serialization (not XML or similar). Qt [offers classes for that](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdatastream.html), which allow you to pass any class known to Qt's meta system into a stream of data.

The problem is that C++ does not really support introspection as a language feature, so you'll have to know the data that is to be serialized.

In many cases a length indicator (use big-endian) followed by the data is a good way to serialize data.