# boost::asio async_write complex structure

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Whats the best way to send a complex structure using boost's asio `async_write`... Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to serialize the structure, some options include

- [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)
- [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/)

I've answered several similar questions when using Boost.Serialization with Boost.Asio, [here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182224/c-objects-serialization-for-linux/3183101#3183101) that may be useful to you.

Comment: That link IS helpful. Thanks.

Comment: One question though, that shows how to use serialization for text, how do I use it to convert to binary?

Comment: @Andrew use `boost::archive::binary_oarchive` instead of `boost::archive::text_oarchive`.