# c++ boost::asio::buffer and structures

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Is there anyway to BASICALLY do the following:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

struct testStruct{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main(){
    struct testStruct t;
    boost::asio::buffer b;
    b = boost::asio::buffer(t); 
    return 0;
}
```

Where it seems to fail is passing 't' into the buffer, 'b'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [scatter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/buffers.html) operation of more than a single buffer:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include <vector>

struct testStruct{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int
main()
{
    struct testStruct t;
    t.x = 5;
    t.y = 7;

    std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> buffers;
    buffers.push_back( boost::asio::buffer(&t.x, sizeof(t.x) ) );
    buffers.push_back( boost::asio::buffer(&t.y, sizeof(t.y) ) );

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket( io_service ); // note not connected!
    std::size_t length = boost::asio::write( socket, buffers );

    return 0;
}
```

Note you'll need to use a corresponding gather on the receiving side. This gets very tedious with anything more than the contrived example you have presented. Which is why [I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599302/boostasio-async-write-complex-structure/5599323#5599323) using a more robust serialization mechanism in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599302/boostasio-async-write-complex-structure).

Comment: Right! That does seem tedious... I'm just trying to get a feel for my options. Thanks for the continued help!

Comment: @Andrew no problem, glad to help! Keep asking questions as you encounter them, that is what Stackoverflow is for.

Comment: `boost::asio::buffer(&t, sizeof(t))` would be much more efficient. Turn packing on/off if needed.

Answer (score 3):

Just Use Boost.Serialization 
You can get a demo from the http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html

When you want to send an Object, It is better for you to Serialize it First.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you need to be careful of.

**1. Padding**

The layout of your struct is implementation-specific. It's entirely possible for there to be placeholder bytes between the x and y members of your struct on the server, and none on the client.

To work around this, you should serialize your structures member by member into a character buffer, and deserialize them on the client in the same manner.

You could write some utility code to help you with this, here's a starting point:

```
class packet_writer
{
public:
    template <typename iter> void write(iter begin, iter end)
    {
        buffer_.insert(buffer_.end(), begin, end);
    }

    template <typename T> void write(T data)
    {
            int8_t* begin = reinterpret_cast<int8_t*>(&data);
        write(begin, begin + sizeof(data));
    }

    const std::vector<int8_t>& buffer() const
    {
        return buffer_;
    }

private:
    std::vector<int8_t> buffer_;
};
```

**2. Endianness**

Depending on architecture, or in some cases even depending on the current CPU mode (some POWER CPUs support endianness switching), the bytes of your members may be reversed. You have to detect the endianness of the host architecture, and swap the bytes to a predefined order for use in your protocol.